# iPad: document on click behaves differently on each browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, onclick

So I have an element and when I click on that, it will toggle open and close.

```
$(document).on("click","#element",function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

So this was not working on an iPad and I searched for the issue on this forum and found different solution and most common one was to add `touchstart`. So I did that. My code is now:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart","#element",function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

Now after adding this I am able to click on the iPad. But on desktop, it seems that it is clicking twice. So if I am clicking, it is opening and closing at the same time.

So I the added `preventDefault` function:

```
$(document).on("click touchstart","#element",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   doSomething();
});
```

Now, Chrome is working good on both iPad and Desktop. Mozilla is good on Desktop but Mozilla on the iPad is same, clicking twice effect.

Comment: Apple made changes in iPadOS 13 that make it act like desktop instead of mobile.

Comment: but right now i am stuck. I need solution for this. please someone

Comment: I don't see any reason why that code should cause any changes on desktop.

Comment: Did you replace the original code with it, or do you have both of them?

Comment: i did replace it. I tested these one by one.

Comment: Earlier i wrote this code outside `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Later i put it inside of `ready` function but no changes.

Comment: If you only have one event binding, it shouldn't run twice.

Comment: Add `console.log(e.type);`, see if you're getting multiple events triggered.

Comment: On my page, there are total of 2-7 click events and every click events toggles it's part.

Comment: When i console on chrome iPad, it says `touchstart` and on mozilla it says touchstart first and then click.

Comment: So just use touchstart, remove click

Comment: then desktop is not working. completely stopped.

Comment: Thats weird. If it's getting touchstart when you say both events, I don't know why it doesn't when you just list it by itself.